# Invoking event_add repeatedly on the same file descriptor with the same timeout

Tags: libevent

If I do the following

1. invoke event_add for a particular file descriptor fd1 and timeout t1
   = 5 seconds
2. after 1 second, without waiting for any event to occur, I call
   event_add again for f1 and t1 = 5 seconds.

---

Will the second invocation of event_add cancel the earlier call? i.e. if the event does not happen, will the timeout now happen at 6 seconds instead of 5 seconds? Or, will we have 2 timeouts - one at 5 and another at 6 seconds

Does this behaviour differ between libevent versions 1 and 2? I did not find any documentation pertaining to this. I’m not able to comprehend this is from a reading of the code. I can obviously write a program to test this out but since the program has to work on different platforms, it would be better if there is a concrete documentation that describes the behaviour under these conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [official documentation (*Making events pending and non-pending* section)](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref4_event.html):

> If you call `event_add()` on an event that is *already* pending, it will leave it pending, and reschedule it with the provided timeout.

So you could expect the event being triggered for timeout after 6 seconds. Of course, any event occuring on the event structure (if associated with a file descriptor for example) between the two calls to `event_add()` will also reset the timer.

---

However, extending the answer with a non-asked piece of advice, pay attention to the following part:

> If the event is already pending, and you re-add it with the timeout `NULL`, `event_add()` will have no effect.

Thus if you want to delete the timeout on an existing event, you could choose between:

1. Using `event_add()` directly with a non-`NULL` timeout set to `{0, 0}`
2. **Deleting/Adding** the event with `event_del()`/`event_add()`, having set a `NULL` timeout this time

I would recommend the latter.